# Json Array List to CSV format

Tags: java, arrays, json, csv, arraylist

I am working on converting JSON object to CSV conversion in the desired format. I tried multiple ways.. but no look. Any points would be highly appreciated.

```
Here is the output I am getting when I get convert JSON object to JSON Array.
         JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(content.toString());

         JSONArray docs = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Results");

          System.out.println("get the array"+docs);
```

Output results are here for now.

```
get the array
[
 {"Item":1,"Status":"Approved","Name":"Brownie","SubmitDate":"2016-04-05T14:06:16Z","ReceivedState":1},
 {"Item":3,"Status":"Approved","Name":"Oats","SubmitDate":"2016-04-19T19:39:25Z","ReceivedState":1},
 {"Item":2,"Status":"Submitted","Name":"Choclate","SubmitDate":"2016-06-01T12:40:19Z","ReceivedState":1},
 ]
```

Now I am expecting the output in below format in csv

```
Item,Status,Name,SubmittedDate,ReceivedState
1,Approved,Brownie,"2016-04-05T14:06:16Z",1
3,Approved,Oats,"2016-04-19T19:39:25Z",1
2,Submitted,Choclate,"016-06-01T12:40:19Z",1
```

the code below is with exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 0

I know because we have ArrayList here stored in docs. I am not sure how I can convert further to the expected CSV format. If anyone could guide would be highly appreciated.

```
File file = new File("C:\\MYVIEW.csv"); 
         String csv =CDL.toString(docs); 
         FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, csv);
```

Let me know if any details needed. Thanks

Comment: what is CDL? [This](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java/blob/master/CDL.java)? Or [this](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/commons/json/util/CDL.html)?

Comment: this 
 https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling5/org/apache/sling/commons/json/util/CDL.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String inputJson = "{Results: [\n" +
            " {\"Item\":1,\"Status\":\"Approved\",\"Name\":\"Brownie\",\"SubmitDate\":\"2016-04-05T14:06:16Z\",\"ReceivedState\":1},\n" +
            " {\"Item\":3,\"Status\":\"Approved\",\"Name\":\"Oats\",\"SubmitDate\":\"2016-04-19T19:39:25Z\",\"ReceivedState\":1},\n" +
            " {\"Item\":2,\"Status\":\"Submitted\",\"Name\":\"Choclate\",\"SubmitDate\":\"2016-06-01T12:40:19Z\",\"ReceivedState\":1},\n" +
            " ]}";
    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(inputJson);
    JSONArray objJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("Results");
    String csv = CDL.toString(objJsonArray);
    System.out.println(csv);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(System.getenv("HOME")+ "/temp.csv"), csv);
}
```

**Output**:

```
Status,Item,SubmitDate,ReceivedState,Name
Approved,1,2016-04-05T14:06:16Z,1,Brownie
Approved,3,2016-04-19T19:39:25Z,1,Oats
Submitted,2,2016-06-01T12:40:19Z,1,Choclate
```